# Where is the "code" field in the Problems pane?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code supports capturing error codes in custom problem matchers. What use are they? They don't seem to be displayed anywhere.

As described by the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher):

> - **code** the match group index for the problem's code. Can be omitted if no code value is provided by the compiler.

For example, take the following tslint error:

```
ERROR: (comment-format) C:/Users/Kendall/Source/ncre/src/ncre.ts[84, 5]: comment must start with uppercase letter
```

Use this problem matcher:

```
"problemMatcher": {
    "owner": "tslint",
    "fileLocation": "absolute",
    "pattern": {
        "regexp": "^(ERROR|WARNING): \\((.+?)\\) (.+?)\\[(\\d+), (\\d+)\\]: (.+)$",
        "severity": 1,
        "code": 2,
        "file": 3,
        "line": 4,
        "column": 5,
        "message": 6
    }
}
```

The error is displayed in the Problems pane like this:

[image]

The code `comment-format` doesn't appear here.

I've verified that it's correctly captured by copying the error and the code does appear in the result:

```
file: 'file:///c%3A/Users/Kendall/Source/ncre/src/ncre.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'comment must start with uppercase letter'
at: '84,5'
source: ''
code: 'comment-format'
```

Am I missing something, or is capturing the error code mostly pointless?

Answer (score 0):

Update: it's implemented in [VSCode September 2018](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_problems-panel). Hooray!